# Slick slider into the jQuery EasyTabs conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, slider

There are two tabs.

Both are contains Slick slider.

First one works fine. But once you tap the second one, it loads nothing.

Well, almost nothing — you'll see in example below.

And if you stay on the second tab and reload your page, it will show you the right content. But then, the first tab will stop working and behave as the second tab was.

As of my poor knowledge of JavaScript, I get that it goes something with how tabs load... but I have no clue how to change it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.tab-container').easytabs({
    animationSpeed: 'fast'
  });

  $('.services__slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    asNavFor: '.services__slider--tap'
  });
  $('.services__slider--tap').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.services__slider',
    centerMode: true,
    focusOnSelect: true
  });
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lypovetsky/LLn90myj/) example of the code.